# Cluster features - get value properties of feature - on style function

Tags: openlayers, clustering

I struggle with not very complicated issue, I need get average values on my cluster features. Without cluster it's OK, I get the value but how to get value in cluster set?

with cluster    value:    `feature.get('tzewn')[i]` - is undefined

without cluster value:    `feature.get('tzewn')`    - is ok.

My style function:

```
var s_t_zew = function(feature, resolution) {
    var fGet; 
    var size = feature.get('features').length;

    for(var i=0; i<size; i++){
        //function isCluster(feature) { if (!feature || !feature.get('features')) { return false;  }

          fGet += **feature.get('tzewn')[i]**; <--- it's undefined
          console.log('i: '+i+',  '+size+' '+ ',  'fGet);
//}
}
..
fGet = fGet/size;
...
text: fGet.toString(),
...
}
```

My GeoJSON:

```
parseResponse({"type":"FeatureCollection","totalFeatures":1314,"features":[{"type":"Feature","id":"v_wezel_tzewn.fid--7639626f_157c2088d0c_7c7e","geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[2572380.517,7010401.8134]},"geometry_name":"geom","properties":{"gis_id":13176,"tzewn":3.5,"bbox":[2572380.517,7010401.8134,2572380.517,7010401.8134]}},
... }
```

How to get value on cluster features?

`feature.get('tzewn')[i]` doesn't work - Cannot read property '0' of undefined,

`parseFloat(feature.valueOf('tzewn')[i])` doesn't work - get NaN

In OpenLayers 2 this works well:

```
sumValue += parseFloat(feature.cluster[i].attributes.tzewn)
```

Comment: No it's not that case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `feature.get('features')[i].get('tzewn')`

Comment: Yes it works. Thanks! Maybe know why fGet += parseFloat(feature.get('features')[i].get('tzewn')); doesn't work? If trying add value get NaN...

Comment: Don't set with init var fGet = 0; just set var fGet; my mistake.